# Windows Store App, Keep media transport controls on screen?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am using a MediaElement control in a Windows Store App I'm developing. I have the property `AreTransportControlsEnabled` set to `true`

The transport controls want to hide after some time, however, and my client wants them to stay visible all the time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not available by default. If I were to try something, I would try creating a DispatchTimer that every `timePeriod` (where the period is less than the time it takes to disappear), it does something like calls [`SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrolsdisplayupdater.update.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). This should trigger it to show again. I don't know if it will repeat its entrance animation (hopefully it will not).

Comment: @NateDiamond That's quite brilliant thinking if it works. I'm wondering then, how do I reference the particular instance of transport controls that can be enabled or disabled with my MediaElement?

Comment: `SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView()` is a `static` method that you can access that should get you whichever SMTC is currently being used (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement - at specific period to prevent the controls from hiding, and here is my solution:

1. In the control template for the transport controls I created additional visual state in the ControlPanelVisibilityStates group called ControlPanelVisible (state where the controls are visible):
2. When I needed to prevent the transport controls from hiding I made a DispatcherTimer to call this visual state every 10 ms:

   KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
   KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
   KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
   {
   VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ControlPanelVisible", true);
   };
   KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer.Start();

This prevented the controls from auto hiding.